# Using str.extract with regex on pandas df column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have some address info. stored in a pandas df column like below:

```
df['Addr']
LT 75 CEDAR WOOD 3RD PL
LTS 22,25 & 26 MULLINS CORNER
LTS 7 & 8
PT LT 22-23 JEFFERSON HIGHLANDS EXTENSION
```

I want to extract lot information and create a new column so for the example above, my expected results are as below:

```
df['Lot']
75
22,25 & 26
7 & 8
22-23
```

This is my code:

```
df['Lot'] = df['Addr'].str.extract(r'\b(?:LOT|LT|LTS?) (\w+(?:-\d+)*)')
```

Results I'm getting is:

```
75
22
7
22-23
```

How can I modify my regex for expected results if at all possible? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\b(?:LOT|LTS?) (\d+(?:(?:[-,]| & )\d+)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?:LOT|LTS?)`  Match `LOT` or `LT` or `LTS`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `(?:(?:[-,]| & )\d+)*` Optionally repeat either `-` or `,` or  `&`  followed by 1+ digits
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JuQvsi/1)

```
data = [
    "LT 75 CEDAR WOOD 3RD PL",
    "LTS 22,25 & 26 MULLINS CORNER",
    "LTS 7 & 8",
    "PT LT 22-23 JEFFERSON HIGHLANDS EXTENSION"
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Addr'])

df['Lot'] = df['Addr'].str.extract(r'\b(?:LO?T|LTS?) (\d+(?:(?:[-,]| & )\d+)*)')

print(df)
```

Output

```
                                        Addr         Lot
0                    LT 75 CEDAR WOOD 3RD PL          75
1              LTS 22,25 & 26 MULLINS CORNER  22,25 & 26
2                                  LTS 7 & 8       7 & 8
3  PT LT 22-23 JEFFERSON HIGHLANDS EXTENSION       22-23
```

---

If the `-` `,` and `&` can all be surrounded by optional whitespace chars, you might shorten the pattern to:

```
 \b(?:LOT|LTS?) (\d+(?:\s*[-,&]\s*\d+)*)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AbKwbb/1)

Comment: Perfect. Could you provide some explanation on `(\d+(?:(?:[-,]| & )\d+)*)`? Why do you have \d+ at the front and end? Is it like start from any number, then include "-" and "," characters or "&" and match any more numbers?

Comment: @mha I have added an explanation and another pattern at the bottom of the answer in case optional whitespace chars can be present for all "separators"

Comment: Hi, what if I have `LTS 22, 25, & 26` instead with an added space after the first ",". Now the regex will only extract `22`. How to solve this?

Comment: @mha If you have different formats like that, a broader pattern could be for example `\b(?:LOT|LTS?) (\d+(?:[-,& ]+\d+)*)` https://regex101.com/r/9cv9Jh/1

Comment: Then I end up including a bunch of other irrelevant information.

Comment: @mha Could you update the content that you have in this link? https://regex101.com/r/9cv9Jh/1 There is a digit missing in the example string, perhaps this would be more precise `\b(?:LOT|LTS?) (\d+(?:(?:\s*[-,&])+\s*\d+)*)\b` https://regex101.com/r/4yO2mx/1

Comment: Nvm, got it resolved thanks a bunch. https://regex101.com/r/Bg8w0A/1